# cell margin for dynamically generated table items

Tags: java, html, margin, padding

There is a huge margin between `Odo` and `Location` columns even though I have set the
width for the `td` tag.

I have a simple table:

```
<table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
       <tr>
        <td width="18%" style="padding-left: 15px">Date</td>
        <td width="16%">Type</td>
        <td width="16%">Odo</td>
        <td width="20%">Location</td>
        <td width="46%">Remark</td>
      </tr>
      {ITEMSLIST}
</table>
```

My above items list is coming dynamically like this:

```
itemList += "<tr><td align='left' style='font-size:8px; color:#03F;padding-left: 15px'>"
                                +displayFormat.format(idate)+ "</td><td style='font-size:8px; color:#03F'>"
+ cur2.getString(0)+ " Practicle</td><td style='font-size:8px; color:#03F'>"
+ "200"+ "</td><td style='font-size:8px; color:#03F'>"
+ location+ "</td><td style='font-size:8px; color:#03F'>"
+ cur2.getString(3) + "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: try removing table width and add table border and see if your dynamically generated tr has any extra space and use trim() is so..

Comment: thanks problem resolved by also defining the same widths for dynamic list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explicitly needed to define the width for all dynamically generated `td` tags and it went just fine-

```
itemList += "<tr><td align='left'  width='18%' style='font-size:8px; color:#03F;padding-left: 15px; '>"+displayFormat.format(idate)
    + "</td><td width='16%' style='font-size:8px; color:#03F'>"
    + cur2.getString(0)+ " Practicle</td><td width='16%' style='font-size:8px; color:#03F'>"
    + "200"+ "</td><td width='20%' style='font-size:8px; color:#03F'>"
    + location
    + "</td><td width='46%' style='font-size:8px; color:#03F'>"
    + cur2.getString(3) + "</td></tr>";
```